# Change the output directory for .css and .js in Semantic UI's gulp tasks

Tags: gulp, semantic-ui

I changed the output paths in my `semantic.json` which is working fine. However I would like the following files to be built in `../../static/css` (`../../static/js`):

- `semantic.css`
- `semantic.js`
- `semantic.min.css`
- `semantic.min.js`

What do I have to change in order to achieve this?

**File content:**

```
{
  "base": "semantic/",
  "paths": {
    "source": {
      "config": "src/theme.config",
      "definitions": "src/definitions/",
      "site": "src/site/",
      "themes": "src/themes/"
    },
    "output": {
      "packaged": "../static/",
      "uncompressed": "../static/components/",
      "compressed": "../static/components/",
      "themes": "../static/themes/"
    },
    "clean": "../static/"
  },
  "permission": false,
  "autoInstall": false,
  "rtl": false,
  "components": [
    /* Components come here... */
  ],
  "version": "2.2.13"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the output directories in the `Semantic.json` didn't work for me, but changing it in `semantic/tasks/config/defaults.js` worked. I don't know why or if that's good, but the files have been created correctly now.

As to your problem with separating CSS and JS:
Here (https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2221) it says:

> JS and CSS files are not set up to have separate output directories in
>   the current build system.

As of July 2016 there was [no solution](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2413) yet.